# GBA dev - Affine sprite pauses every 90 degrees, BG unaffected

Tags: c, sprite, affinetransform, game-boy-advance

**EDIT**: 
I have stripped the program down to its basics: https://github.com/aidan-aidan/temp/blob/master/source/vpp.c

I have posted this question over at the gba-dev forums but they seem pretty dead and I have not gotten a response after many days.

Here is a video showing the problem: http://youtu.be/8gweFiSobwc (different from the code above, you can run the rom if you want to see it)

As you can see the BG rotation is unaffected, though they use the same LUT and they have the same data types in their structures as each other.

I have redone the LUT a few times to no avail, and this problem only surfaced after switching to 2048 circle divisions rather than 256.

Looking at the memory viewer in VBA, I can see that pb is not behaving the same as pa. pa ranges from 0x0100 to 0 as I would expect (same as 1 to 0), but pb ranges from 0 to 0x0096 when the gun is right from the center line, but jumps up to 0xFFFF as soon as it goes left from the center line. The only thing I can figure is that it is going negative (which makes sense, as cosine of that angle should result in a negative number), but I don't fully understand ones complement so i can't be sure. 0 "degrees" is horizontal on the right for the gun. 512 would be ninety degrees.

I have included everything I can think of, any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There's a fair bit of code in there dealing with indirect register accesses through your sprite structures, support for multiple bullets, backgrounds, unused game modes, math, etc. Can you boil it all down for us into a minimal example of just the sprite rotation issue and as little else as possible?

Comment: I have boiled it all down, the issue still remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As near as I can tell the program is technically working correctly. Instead your visual artifacts stem from the limited 8-bit fixed-point precision in the affine transformation used by the hardware.

Essentially the difference between a 0 and 1 in the sine tables makes a rather large and visible jump in the rotation for the right-angles in your rectangular sprite, while the 0°/90°/180°/270° corners are not that special for the round earth background.

The tangent for the (co-)sine function at 0 is high, so if you look at your tables there is only a single spot where they are precisely 0. If the rotation doesn't fall precisely on this index the result looks visibly skewed.

What you may try however is to cheat by fiddling with the rounding to produce more consecutive zeroes. At the moment you table generator is scaling by 256 and rounding towards the nearest integer:

```
sine[i] = floor(sin(i * M_PI / 1024.0) * 256.0 + 0.5);
```

As an alternative we may skew the table a little by rounding towards zero, as is the default in C, and increasing the scale to insure that the table still reaches 256 for at more than one entry.

```
int value = sin(i * M_PI / 1024.0) * 257.0;
if(value < -256) value = -256;
if(value > +256) value = +256;
sine[i] = value;
```

The table may be then flattened even further by increasing the scaling factor even further.

---

The problem is also that for small sprites near right angles there is nowhere for the rotation to go.

Picture a 64x1 straight line sprite pointing vertically at nearly an almost straight angle, with only the minimum 1/256th fractional step from the sine table. Keep in mind that the rotation is always centered so you get one jagged horizontal step precisely at the center.

For each of the 32 pixels from the center outwards you then add up another 1/256th fraction to the texture coordinate. However all of these together only make for 1/8th of a pixel in total and so no more horizontal steps are taken. In fact for this sprite shape you will see no visible change until the rotation angle reaches a full 8/256th fraction.

On the other hand your large earth object is sufficiently big to always show multiple visible integer "steps." This means that an increased rotation angle will always at least shift the position of the non-centered step, even if it insufficient to add up to another full pixel along entire side. The result is a smoother overall effect due to the continual animation.

Comment: I will try this again, though it did not help when i tried it before, I saw that too and thought that was why and it makes sense. When I was only using 256 angle measurements,  there was not artifact, which I think I understand why just can't put into words.

Comment: There I have tried it and it has not worked. I still get the same artifact. I don't understand why the switching of my angle divisions like that messed it up and I really don't understand why the BG rotation is totally unaffected.

Comment: I would love to get to the bottom of this, can people tell me why they can't give me an answer? not enough info?

Comment: I'd say it helps a bit, especially if you increase the zoom slightly, but it is never going to be perfect at such a low resolution and precision. Here is a quick demo at 260x: http://sites.google.com/site/doynax/files/spin.zip

Comment: how come it worked just fine when at 256 angle divisions? Im sorry I don't have anything to show from then but I do remember it being nice and smooth.

Comment: In your code you used a scaling factor of 270? perhaps i will try this instead.